# Quickbooks Online Plus: How to Import transaction data

Tags: import, transactions, quickbooks-online

Other than Vendor, Customer, Chart of Account and Bank Transaction, I would like to import expense and sales transactions without manually inputting the data to the Transaction > Sales or Transaction > Expenses tab? What format should I use?

Answer (score 3):

Intuit has pages and pages and pages of documentation on this very topic.

> Other than Vendor, Customer, Chart of Account and Bank Transaction, I would like to import expense and sales transactions without manually inputting the data to the Transaction > Sales or Transaction > Expenses tab?

Here is their documentation:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting

Basically, you use OAuth to authenticate, and their REST API to push data to them.

Here is a reference to all the different types of transactions they support:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/api/accounting#/transaction-entities

> What format should I use?

Intuit supports both XML and JSON. It doesn't matter which you choose -- choose the one you're more comfortable with.

Or, use the libraries and the abstract away the raw JSON/XML:

- PHP: https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php
- Others: https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0100_accounting/0500_developer_kits